# How to change Comment color in Netbeans IDE 8.2?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8.2

How to change Comment color in Netbeans IDE 8.2?

Is it possible?

Comment: What have you researched so far?

Comment: In the top menu: **Tools -> Options** then select the **Fonts & Colors** button then select **NetBeans** in the Profile combo box then select the **Syntax** Tab then in the **Category** column select **Comment**. Change to the color(s) you want on the right side of the panel using the **Foreground** and **Background** color combo boxes.

Comment: Thanks for answered. But i want to change as though comment 1 is blue color and comment 2 is red color..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

First go to Tools menu

[image: Tools]

and click on options,

[image: options]

Now select Font and Colors tab
[image: font]

Then select comment from the list which is in 'syntax' tab and to the right side of the list you can change font, foreground, background and also effects.

Alternatively you can change entire appearance by selecting a theme (Look and Feel) from,

Tools->Options->appearance tab->Look and Feel tab.

Comment: Thanks for answered. But i want to change as though comment 1 is blue color and comment 2 is red color..

Answer (score 0):

For mac:
Netbeans - > Preferences (May be options for windows, idk) -> Font&Colors

There is a category option, select that and there will be foreground, if you change that colour, your comment colour will changed.

Comment: Thanks for answered. But i want to change as though comment 1 is blue color and comment 2 is red color..